# Exposing a kubernetes pod via service in kind kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kind

I'm following the tutorial here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) to test a local development setup for kubernetes. However, I am using kind, instead of minikube.

At the moment, I am stuck on step 3:

```
minikube service hello-node
```

which is supposed to expose a LoadBalancer service.

However, kind doesn't seem to have such a command, and I am wondering how I would expose the service from the tutorial.

My set up is a WSL2 distro with docker, kind, and kubectl. My current port bridges are:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
b62c43ac3b2e        kindest/node:v1.17.0   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   49 minutes ago      Up 49 minutes       127.0.0.1:32769->6443/tcp   kind-control-plane
```

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://127.0.0.1:32769
KubeDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:32769/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

and

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-node   LoadBalancer   10.96.65.157   <pending>     8080:31578/TCP   46m
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          51m
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LoadBalancer` type service internally creates `NodePort`. So you can access it via `http://NODEIP:31578` where `31578` is the NodePort as you can see in output of `kubectl get service`. To get `NODEIP` you can use `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

If you look at the output of `minikube service hello-node` it's has got the same `NODEIP` and `NODEPORT`. Unfortunately there is no equivalent command in kind and so you need to use the method described above.

`EXTERNAL-IP` will be pending because there is no cloud(AWS, GCP, Azure) like implementation in local kind cluster. If you really want to make `LoadBalancer` type service work you can use metallb as loadbalancer implementation. In this way you will have `EXTERNAL-IP` assigned instead of `pending` and you can use that IP to access the pod.

[Here](https://mauilion.dev/posts/kind-metallb/) is a guide on how to make metallb with kind work.